# Firebase relatime database add google authenticated users

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-signin

I'm trying to add users to realtime database who are authenticated using google as shown below

```
document.getElementById("btnGoogleLogin").addEventListener('click', function () {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
        .then((result) => {
            // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
            const token = credential.accessToken;
           
            // The signed-in user info.
            const user = result.user;
       
            const userId = user.uid;
            const email = user.email;
            const imageUrl = user.photoURL;
            const name = user.displayName;

            const dbRef = ref(database);
            console.log("Current User:" + userId);
            get(dbRef, '/users' + userId).then((snapshot) => {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    console.log(snapshot.val());
                } else {
                    console.log("First time user..Need to add it to db");
                    writeUserData(userId, email, imageUrl, name)
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });

        }).catch((error) => {
            // Handle Errors here.
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            const email = error.email;
            // The AuthCredential type that was used.
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
            console.log(error);
        });
});


function writeUserData(userId, email, imageUrl, name) {
    set(ref(database, '/' + userId), {
        email: email,
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        name: name
    })
        .then(() => {
            window.location.href = "https://www.mysite.default.html";
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // The write failed...
        });
}
```

The problem is first time it add user under users db and when a new user who login using google is not being added to the existing users db but added in authetication.

I am not sure how to get rid of this.

Comment: You're missing a slash after `/users` in here ` get(dbRef, '/users' + userId)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - So it should be get(dbRef, '/users/' + userId) (or) get(dbRef, 'users/' + userId)

Comment: Both do the same. The leading `/` is optional, but the one between `users` and `userId` isn't.

Comment: I did but the second user is not adding to the previous user..I am not sure something might be missed. I am able to see the second user in authentication but not in realtime database.

Comment: Did you already set breakpoints and run the code in a debugger? Does it reach the `set(ref(database, '/' + userId), {...})` in the problem scenario? Does it reach the `catch` by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as commented by @Frank, there must be a `/` between `'users'` and `userId`. Then `get()` takes only 1 parameter of type [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.query) (or a [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.databasereference)) but you are passing 2 and hence the `get()` is querying `dbRef` which means the entire database. The database might be empty by default and hence the first user gets added but there after `snapshot.exists()` would always be true and newer users are not added.

Using `child()` to create a DatabaseReference should resolve this:

```
import { child, get } from "firebase/database"

const userRef = child(dbRef, 'users/' + userId);

get(userRef).then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  } else {
    console.log("First time user..Need to add it to db");
    writeUserData(userId, email, imageUrl, name)
  }
})
```

Comment: Perfect..This is what I'm missing..Thanks for pointing me out in the right way.